# Different transition animations between the same two states

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Is it possible to use different transition animations between two states in a QML component? The following example doesn't work and the program crashes (*segmentation fault* on Linux):

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: canvas
    height: 500; width: 600

    Rectangle { id: rect; color: "#04A"; height: 100; width: 100 }

    state: "A"
    states: [
        State { name: "A"; PropertyChanges { target: rect; x: 0; y: 100 } },
        State { name: "B"; PropertyChanges { target: rect; x: 500; y: 100 } }
    ]


    transitions: trans1

    property list<Transition> trans1: [
        Transition {
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; duration: 500 }
        }
    ]

    property list<Transition> trans2: [
        Transition {
            from: "A"; to: "B"
            SequentialAnimation {
                NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; from: 0; to: -100; duration: 250 }
                NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; from: 600; to: 500; duration: 250 }
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: "B"; to: "A"
            SequentialAnimation {
                NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; from: 500; to: 600; duration: 250 }
                NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; from: -100; to: 0; duration: 250 }
            }
        }
    ]


    // test script /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Timer { interval: 1000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "B" }
    Timer { interval: 2000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "A" }

    // change kind of transition
    Timer { interval: 3000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.transitions = trans2 }

    Timer { interval: 4000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "B" }
    Timer { interval: 5000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "A" }
}
```

The [QML-Doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-item.html#transitions-prop) says that the `transtition` property is *read-only*, but usually a list of `Transition{...}` elements is assigned to this property, so it can't be really read-only, can it?

One solution would be to use 4 states, e.g. `A1`, `B1`, `A2` and `B2`, and define a transition between `A1` and `B1`, that looks like `trans1` and another transition between `A2` and `B2`, that looks like `trans2`.
**But I want to know if something like this is possible without introducing new states.**

---

**Edit:**

The suggestion of *gregschlom* to change the `from`/`to` properties works, here an example:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: canvas
    height: 500; width: 600

    Rectangle { id: rect; color: "#04A"; height: 100; width: 100 }

    state: "A"
    states: [
        State { name: "A"; PropertyChanges { target: rect; x: 0; y: 100 } },
        State { name: "B"; PropertyChanges { target: rect; x: 500; y: 100 } }
    ]


    property int transType: 1

    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: transType == 1 ? "*" : "none"
            to:   transType == 1 ? "*" : "none"
            ParallelAnimation {
                RotationAnimation { target: rect; property: "rotation"; from: 0; to:360; duration: 500 }
                NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; duration: 500 }
            }
        },
        Transition {
            from: transType == 2 ? "*" : "none"
            to:   transType == 2 ? "*" : "none"
            NumberAnimation { target: rect; property: "x"; duration: 500 }
        }
    ]


    // test script /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Timer { interval: 1000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "B" }
    Timer { interval: 2000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "A" }

    // change kind of transition
    Timer { interval: 3000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.transType = 2 }

    Timer { interval: 4000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "B" }
    Timer { interval: 5000; running: true; onTriggered: canvas.state = "A" }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following example doesn't work and the program crashes (segmentation fault on Linux):

Please, do report crashes like that to https://bugreports.qt.io. Crashes are given maximum priority and are usually fixed in a few days.

> The QML-Doc says that the transtition property is read-only, but usually a list of Transition{...} elements is assigned to this property, so it can't be really read-only, can it?

I *think* assigning at run-time (ie: in a script) is different than assigning in your qml file, so when the say "read-only" maybe they meant you're not supposed to *change* the value once it has been initialized.

Anyways, if the doc say it's read-only, and it crashes when you try to write to it, then you know you're probably not supposed to do it... :)

> But I want to know if something like this is possible without introducing new states.

The qml doc on Transitions says:

> If multiple Transitions are specified, only a single (best-matching) Transition will be applied for any particular state change. In the example above, when changing to state1, the first transition will be used, rather than the more generic second transition.

So you could try be defining all your transitions at once and change the "to" and "from" settings dynamically to try to enable / disable a transition. Not sure if it's possible, but it could work.